# Restrict iframe width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Second ever question, and second for today. I'm writing a web/mobile app in HTML5/Javascript using Intel SDK.

After getting through the JSON problem I was having earlier I'm now having a problem restricting the width of an iframe - which seems like it should be very simple, but I'm obviously missing something.

I'm starting with an iframe called like so:

```
<div class="widget uib_w_6 d-margins" data-uib="media/iframe" data-ver="0">
<iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

I then use

```
document.getElementById('myframe').src = "http://URL.here" + productName;
```

to set the src, and this is working fine.

However, as the web page its loading is bigger than the size of my phone screen, it's making the iframe as wide as required by the website, no matter how I try to restrict its width.

Ideally I'd like to 'squeeze' the framed website down to the width of the screen in the app (the app is responsive size, as XDK did this automatically), but I'd settle for the iframe using the available space and allowing me to scroll the frame, rather than the whole app scrolling.

I've tried:

```
<iframe id="myframe" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I've tried adding 100% width into the surrounding div. I've even tried restricting the iframe width (as above) to the resolution width of an iphone 6 (width=370) in both the iframe itself and the surrounding div, and neither work - no matter what I do, the frame, once provided with its src from above, just goes full size and makes the app scroll sideways.

Any thoughts? I'm reading about tricks people use that seem to usually be used for embedding youtube videos...

Standard apology - total noob, and I think this might be more simple than I'm making it.

Comment: When I set a width using CSS it does work. Have you tried using CSS?

Comment: I haven't yet, I'll try some CSS

Comment: Try to set border to 0 in css `border: 0;` or add `frameborder="0"` attribute to iframe tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is what you're looking for, but you can scale elements using CSS3 transformations:

```
<style>
    .scaled {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>

<iframe src="http://some.target.url/page" class="scaled" />
```

You can find some more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

This will actually "zoom" (or "squeeze" as you say ;)) the element, making its content smaller. Maybe you need to calculate the ratio using JavaScript, if you can't find a "hard-coded" value which always works for your scenario.

And, if you like, you can still set a `width` on the `iframe` itself, to specify the actual size you want.
Maybe you could use `100vw` instead of pixels, to relate to 100% of the width of the viewport.

As most of this is CSS3 stuff (`transform`, `vw`), you should ensure that the browsers which will access the site support these features before using this approach.

Comment: Thanks. As soon as I'm back at my desk I'll give this a try.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I had a play with transform tonight, and I ended up with this doing the trick:

All I needed to do on top of this was use transform-origin to stick it to the 'top left' otherwise the iframe was loading well off screen and needing a scroll around to find it.